# Position vs Part

Tags: list-manipulation

What's the difference between `Part` and `Position`?

How can I "move" from the form used by `Part` to that of `Position` (and vicerversa?)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) & [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)

Comment: The results of Position are usually used in combination with Extract that precisely uses the format returned by Position.

Answer (score 8):

The part specification used by [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) is shared by [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html):

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 5}];

pos = Position[g, _Directive]

Extract[g, pos]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 11, 2}}
>
> {Directive[ (* omitted *) ], Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]]}
> ```

Note that `Extract` supports extracting multiple disjoint subexpressions at once.  `Part` can only extract one of these at a time.*  Each part specification such as `{1, 1, 3, 1}` needs to be converted from a list into a bare sequence.  Available methods include pattern replacement and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)/[`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) along with [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at level one (short form `@@@`):

```
Replace[pos, {x__} :> g[[x]], 1]

g[[##]] & @@@ pos
```

---

* *These* meaning the two elements in `pos` in my example.  `Part` specifications at each level may be disjoint but apply to all parts in the extraction.  Positions must have all but the last index in common.

```
m = Partition[Range@9, 3]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  4 & 5 & 6 \\
>  7 & 8 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
m[[2, {1, 3}]]
```

> ```
> {4, 6}
> ```

Index `2` applies to all elements extracted; one cannot extract (only) elements 4 and 9 with a single evaluation of `Part` for example, whereas you can with `Extract`:

```
Extract[m, {{2, 1}, {3, 3}}]
```

Comment: Argh, I hate it when commenting from the review queue (no answers shown) only to discover later on that your comment is fully superfluous.

Comment: @Sjoerd You'll notice that I have a conspicuously low ranking in the review queues relative to my other participation.  I often resort to opening each question separately and acting from there as I don't like the limited information in the queue.

Comment: I like the queue as I spend 80-90% of my time here using an iPad. It's slightly more convenient that way (but only slightly; selecting SE stuff is a challenge on any iOS device).